# Why doesn't window.confirm have an asyc callback?

Tags: javascript, browser

I don't get the point of `confirm` since it doesn't have a callback function? It makes it unusable for me.

One thing I'm working on is getting geocoded information from Google. And I made a function to help with that:

```
codeLatLng(lat, lng, callback)
```

Then in the callback

```
function callback(address) {
  if (confirm(address)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

`//Do something` never happens! Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: If you do not like window.confirm, write your own confirm...Plenty of frameworks have modal dialogs.

Comment: `Do something` should happen if you press OK. Anyways, windows.confirm will cause JavaScript to wait on the user to click on OK/Cancel before proceeding, if you need code to run during the the the popup shows up, you need to implement your own confirm box, one that just sits on the page alone.

Comment: "Why…" you should ask browser developers, [*window.confirm*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#simple-dialogs) is from the very early days of browser scripting. The content of the OP does not seem to be consistent with the subject, and if the confirm appears and *do something* does not happen when "OK" is selected then you have a problem with your code.